# drupa6 node_view add fields

Tags: drupal-6

How to insert the form and fields in the node view,

For example,

i have page content type,

i put the article called "How to handle laptop" , and i published that content ,

now i go in the home, i find that articles displayed in the home,

Then i hit the article , then showed the article title and and article body ,

Now i want to insert the form and field in the node view,

This form purpose is forward to his/her friends,

i need the textfield and send mail button,

"So how to insert the form fields in the content / noew view"

Thanks
Bharanikumar

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module that implements hook_nodeapi() and a form function.

```
/**
 * Implentation of hook_nodeapi().
 */
function yourmodulesname_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser, $page) {
  global $user;
  switch($op) {    
    case 'view': //only show on viewing node types
      // Add your own form as a content item
      $node->content['my_special_form'] = array(
        '#value' => drupal_get_form('my_special_entry_form', $node),
        '#weight' => 11,
      );
      break;
  }
}
```

And then you need to implement form functions according to the Drupal Form API ([6](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6)/[7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7)) in the same file as the above code (*.module):

```
/**
 * Defining the form for entering an annotation
 */
function my_special_entry_form($form_state, $node) {
  // look at documentation for the Drupal Form API
}

/**
 * Handle form validation.
 */
function my_special_entry_form_validate($form, $form_state) {
  // look at documentation for the Drupal Form API
}

/**
 * Handle form submission.
 */
function my_special_entry_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  // look at documentation for the Drupal Form API
}
```

Hope this help to anyone who finds this answer.